# Wordpress jQuery script is not starting on one instance with jQuery.noConflict usage

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have Wordpress 2 instances: local and remote (remote should be very similar, it was mainly uploaded from local except from a few plugins). Code is using jQuery.noConflict method, because without it it was not working locally after adding a lot of plugins. Now when it's uploaded to remote Wordpress, it's still not starting there, but it works locally :). JS method is just not started. For sure file is attached with proper path in HEAD section of HTML file. No errors displayed in console.

**Expected behaviour is: JS alert should appear but it not.**

JS code is here:

```
var jQueryAlias = jQuery.noConflict();       

function customizeWebUIForEmailSubscriberPlugin() {
        alert("customizeWebUIForEmailSubscriberPlugin"); 
        //format input button
        jQueryAlias('#elp_txt_email').removeClass('elp_textbox_class').addClass('form-control').addClass('full-width');

        //format input button
        jQueryAlias('#elp_txt_email').removeClass('elp_textbox_class').addClass('form-control').addClass('full-width');

        //format message text
        //jQuery('.elp_msg').removeClass('elp_msg').addClass('post-body');
        jQueryAlias('#elp_msg').addClass('message-format');


        //hide submit button
        jQueryAlias('#elp_txt_button').addClass('hide');        

        //hide email label
        jQueryAlias('.elp_lablebox').addClass('hide');        
    }

    jQueryAlias(customizeWebUIForEmailSubscriberPlugin);
```

Comment: What behaviour are you expecting from the last line of your code? It's wrapping a function in a jQuery object...?

Comment: I just want to be sure it starts...  so the alert should appear  !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that on both servers (local and remote) jQuery lib is attached in HEAD tag in different sequence. On my local machine: jQuery was attached after script.js and that worked. For remote: jQuery was attached after my script.js. I am not sure why it works in such way on my remote machine.

**Solution:**
After adding code

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>
```

right after HEAD tag, it works:).

Answer (score 1):

Try the following. The function should fire on `document.ready`, but you can also call it whenever you like.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    function customizeWebUIForEmailSubscriberPlugin() {
        alert("customizeWebUIForEmailSubscriberPlugin");
        //format input button
        $('#elp_txt_email').removeClass('elp_textbox_class').addClass('form-control').addClass('full-width');

        //format input button
        $('#elp_txt_email').removeClass('elp_textbox_class').addClass('form-control').addClass('full-width');

        //format message text
        //jQuery('.elp_msg').removeClass('elp_msg').addClass('post-body');
        $('#elp_msg').addClass('message-format');
        //hide submit button
        $('#elp_txt_button').addClass('hide');

        //hide email label
        $('.elp_lablebox').addClass('hide');
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        customizeWebUIForEmailSubscriberPlugin();
    });
});
```

### Edit:

In order to add jquery in WP, add this code to the bottom of your theme's functions.php file, before the closing php tag tat looks like this: `?>`:

```
function pk_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
add_action('pk_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_enqueue_scripts');
```

Comment: This is not optimal:) it  can start it twice:)....but it not working on my remote instance... strange

Comment: That was an example. Once your function is defined inside the jQuery scope, you will be able to call it from anywhere else in your script, but not outside of it. As for your remote problem, check your Console: Maybe one of the plugins you have active in your remote server is generating a JS error, preventing the rest of the code to execute. Right click, inspect element, Console tab.

Comment: Unfortunately: 1) I uninstalled all redundant plugins 2) no errors in FF console 3) No errors displayed on page. Result: still problem exists.

Comment: Try calling the function on `$(window).load()` instead of on `$(document).ready()`. Also, could you provide a link to your remote site?

Comment: $(window).load - it's not working locally. No errors. I think this is a problem with WordPress

Comment: That is very strange. I work with WP **a lot** and never experienced such behavior that was not coming from a faulty plugin or error being generated on the JS side of things. A link to your remote site would definitely help!

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`. You need to enqueue jQuery so that jQuery-based scripts can work. Will edit my answer so as to reflect how to do this.

Comment: You see it in FF console? I dont see it:)

Comment: Chrome. Make sure you are not filtering out errors.

Comment: Now I  see it:)... strange that it works locally... all code is the same

Comment: What I see .. my script is defined after jquery script tag in HTML. MAybe this is a problem?

Comment: Yeah, it is. You need to call jquery first. Try adding jquery as a dependency (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script)  when you register your script. That should fix it.

Comment: Exactly: problem is that for both site, jquery is attached after (remote site) or before my script (local site, it works ).

Comment: Let me know if you can make it work. If the dependency stuff does not work, try playing with the `priority` parameter of `add_action`. Anything greater than the default, which is `10`, should come after, so that way you can make sure jquery will be already enqueued before your script comes in.